# Access Unit and AUD in Transport Stream

Tags: h.264, video-processing, mpeg2-ts

What data should an access unit contain?

```
    [SPS][PPS][IDR][PFrame][BFrame]
```

is an access unit?
I got the concept that, access unit delimiters are required in ts packet. But, if the source file(I am using .264 file as input) do not contain AUD? then should I add AUD explicitly? If yes, then of how many bytes?
Should it be the following?

```
    0x00000169(of Header+1 Byte)
```

And where should I add the AUD?
Currently my TS file contains this formation:

```
    [TS Header][PES Header][SPS][PPS][IDR][PFrame][BFrame][TS Header]...
```

Is this structure okay? Also, can one access unit contain multiple I frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> f the source file does not contain AUD should I add AUD explicitly?

YES

> Also, can one access unit contain multiple I frames

No, an an access unit is analogous to a single frame, they are used to explesit delimit frames. Hence the name.

> 0x00000169(of Header+1 Byte)

0x00000169FF80  just use this for the AUD. You can hard code it.

Comment: thanks @szatmary. and what about the formation of AU? Is  the following okay?      
 [TS Header][PES Header][AUD][SPS][PPS][IDR][PFrame][BFrame][TS Header]...

Comment: No. You have three frames in one Access unit/PES. Also note that a frame may be more that one slice.

Comment: well, so    [TS Header][PES Header][AUD][SPS][PPS][IDR][combination of P Slice and B Slice][TS Header]... should be okay,, right? and I should continue until I find next SPS. am I right?

Comment: No. An IDR frame will contain only IDR slices (no p slices, no b slices). And no, SPS do not delimit access units (if they did, why would we need AUD?).  As an example: TS/PES/AUD/SPS/PPS/IDR/TS/PES/AUD/B SLICE/TS/PES/AUD/P SLICE/TS/PES/AUD/IDR.

Comment: thanks @szatmary, much clear. now, if my source file(.264) has NALUs in the sequence : SPS/PPS/IDR/P Slice/B Slice/P Slice/B Slice/B Slice...
then can my my output file sequence be like TS/PES/AUD/SPS/PPS/IDR/TS/PES/AUD/P Slice/TS/PES/AUD/B Slice/... ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. A single AU can have multiple slices. And they can be of different types (except IDR where all slices must be IDR). The only way to tell is to parse the slice header to see if it contains all the macroblocks in the frame. If you know your encoder produces one slice or frame, you can skip that.